# How to create auto populating Workflow with Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, crm

I need to create an on demand workflow that will auto populate custom entities in CRM that are not related to each other..

`Opportunity/ Opportunity Services` fields need to populate `CurrentContract/CurrentContract Services` entities.

The fields are related as `Opportunity Services > Opportunities > Account < CurrentContract < CurrentContract Services`.

All fields from `Opportunities` need to create a `CurrentContract` and `CurrentContract Services` with identical information.

Comment: You most likely would need to write code to do this in a WF assembly.

Comment: sounds like the only way you'll be able to make the various connections is via some custom activities which you can then call via a workflow

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other comments that [a Custom Workflow Activity](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com.au/blog/roshanmehta/2013/02/21/dynamics-crm-2011-online-custom-workflow-activities!) would be needed.

Another option would be to perform the action using JScript.  There are pros/cons when moving the logic client-side, but some of the [CRM REST libraries](http://crmrestkit.codeplex.com/) make it pretty easy to perform CRUD operations.  Since you said "on demand workflow", you may want to consider client-side for user experience reasons.